# Oracle, regexp_substr - how to match 'string'+regex

Tags: oracle

I have a column that gives me lines like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xSettings>
    <systemPropertyName>BLALBLA</systemPropertyName>
    <minimumAmount>198.00</minimumAmount>
    <closingAmount>198.00</closingAmount>
    <useThisSetting>true</useThisSetting>
    <SystemStep dayAfterPrevious="0">
        <System SystemService="1" minimumAmount="450.00" />
    </SystemStep>
    <SystemStep dayAfterPrevious="8">
        <message />
    </SystemStep>
    <SystemStep dayAfterPrevious="3">
        <block />
    </SystemStep>
    <SystemStep dayAfterPrevious="1">
        <message />
    </SystemStep>
    <SystemStep dayAfterPrevious="7">
        <message />
    </SystemStep>
</xSettings>
```

All numbers in it are variable and the BLA BLA is variable too. What I want is a select that only gives me

```
<minimumAmount>198.00</minimumAmount>
```

though this would be eve better:

```
198.00
```

basically, I can't figure out how to use regexp_substr to find a specific string , then return a number just after that may be from 1 to 4 digits and has two decimals after.

Comment: As MT0 says - don't use regular expressions to extract values from xml strings. It's like driving screws with a hammer; it can be done, but we *should* use a screwdriver.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use regular expressions to parse XML data - use a proper XML parser:

```
SELECT x.minimumAmount
FROM   your_table t,
       XMLTable(
         '/xSettings',
         PASSING XMLType( t.your_column )
         COLUMNS minimumAmount NUMBER(5,2) PATH './minimumAmount'
       ) x
```

Or

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(
         EXTRACTVALUE( XMLType( your_column ), '/xSettings/minimumAmount' )
       ) AS minimumAmount
FROM   your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

XML data should not be queried using regular expressions, but here:

```
select
  regexp_substr(col, '<minimumAmount>(.*)</minimumAmount>',1,1,null,1) minimum_amount
from your_table;
```

One other way is to use `regexp_replace` like this:

```
select
  regexp_replace(col, '.*<minimumAmount>(.*)</minimumAmount>.*','\1') minimum_amount
from your_table;
```

Comment: While this will work, MT0 is right: one should not use regexp functions to query xml data.

Comment: it seems we'll "see" each other here often, so be warned: I am not always right; actually I am wrong often enough!